# I am doing my NEA dice game and I can't make the rounds add up

Tags: python

I've tried many ways and still can't find a way to make it work!
I've tried making a variable which adds the total after each round to itself. `endtotal = endtotal + totalscore`.
I haven't tried other ways yet but I thought I would ask on here first so I'm not trying different methods and failing every time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Hey apebrian, welcome to StackOverflow. it would help if your question provided some context as to how rounds are ended and created. Please provide some sample code which helps people understand the complexity of your question. Also a quick tip: please dont ask a question if you declare you didnt spend the effort to try different things yourself yet, people will be more reluctant answering your question. A last tip: Please reread your question and read it as if you would be answering it, what would you still need to help yourself out. ... Thank you for contributing

Comment: Can you please post at least a *section* of your code, so that we can tell how your rounds work, how they should add up?

Comment: ... its a method approach question. Details here would dilute what its actually about. Here its "how/where to use vars, while-loops, and conditions to show the summarized end-result from various temporary results".

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of OP posting code: use a while-loop and variables to be set outside. In the example of using vars outside the loop the endtotal is each round increased by the defined totalscore and printed as a sum at the end.

```py
count_rounds = 0
rounds       = 10
endtotal     = 0          
totalscore   = 69

while count_rounds < rounds :
    endtotal = endtotal + totalscore
    count_rounds += 1

print ("I'm done with the rounds counting. End score: %s" % endtotal)
```

You'll get the hang of it and how to implement when you'll check out the example. (I assume you know how to work this out using defs.). Enjoy.